# using changeset for larger region to update OSM data in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, osmosis

I'm using the OSM import and update workflow described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94352/update-database-via-osmosis-and-osm2pgsql-too-slow) to maintain OSM data in a PostGIS database.

Import (osm2pgsql):

```
osm2pgsql -c -d gps -U gps --cache 8000 --number-processes 4 --slim --flat-nodes europe_nodes.bin europe-latest.osm.pbf
```

Update (osmosis):

```
osmosis --read-replication-interval workingDirectory=/osmosisworkingdir/ --simplify-change --write-xml-change - | osm2pgsql --append -d gps -U gps --cache 1000 --number-processes 4 --slim --flat-nodes europe_nodes.bin -
```

I want to gradually import new countries into my database while keeping all the data up to date. To avoid the hastle of creating osmosis working directories for each new country and managing more and more separate updates, I would like to use changesets for the entire region.

**Example: Germany and France are imported into the database using osm2pgsql. Changesets for all of Europe are then applied daily using osmosis.**

Will this work properly, considering the changeset contains irrelevant changes to data I don't have? Will this approach have any undesired consequences?